# MySQL - Как узнать сколько дней прошло с начала месяца

Tags: mysql, sql

Как узнать кол-во прошедших с начала текущего месяца дней? Это нужно для выборки ежемесячной статистики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
select DATEPART(day,getdate())
```

Comment: я извиняюсь у меня mysql

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин тогда во первых почему вы этого не указали в вопросе. А вот вторых найти как делается в вашей БД то что уже известно как делается в другой можно элементарно. достаточно набрать в гугле название функции в другой БД и название своей БД т.е. "DATEPART MySQL"

Comment: SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE())

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date as date
declare @datefirst as date
set @date=GETDATE()
set @datefirst=dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,@date)))
select DATEDIFF(day,@datefirst,@date)
```